# Is there a known isotope that generates anti-matter?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter, radioactivity, isotopes

I heard that even a banana generates a minute quantity of antimatter. Does any know radioactive nuclear reaction produce antimatter along with alpha, beta and gamma radiation?

Comment: positrons can be emitted sometimes from beta decay instead of an electron. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_nuclide).

Answer (score 26):

Bananas are [notorious for having high levels of potassium](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-34225517), though a quick Google will find plenty of other potassium rich foods. Anyhow, one of the common radioactive isotopes of potassium is [potassium-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium-40). This mostly decays by emission of an electron and anti-neutrino but rarely it can decay by emission of a positron i.e. anti-matter. So it is true that bananas emit minute quantities of anti-matter.

But ...

Bananas don't emit a **net** amount of antimatter because the electron is always paired with an anti-neutrino and the positron is always paired with a (not anti) neutrino. The number of particles emitted is always equal to the number of anti-particles emitted. This always true and is the result of conservation of lepton number.

Comment: It might be fun to quantify your "rarely". I was surprised to learn from your potassium-40 Wikipedia link that K-40 decays an estimated 4,900 times per second in the human body. So how much anti-matter does a banana produce per second?

Comment: @AaronNovstrup: see the Wikipedia article. 0.001% of decays produce a positron. That's one in every hundred thousand.

Comment: Ah, right, it's all there. A banana produces ~12 positrons a day, if I'm not mistaken. ;)

Comment: Can we assume that any isotope that decays with $\beta^+$ radiation creates antimatter?

Comment: @Crowley: $\beta^+$ (a positron) *is* antimatter, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: so to power that antimatter drive all we need is about one moon sized pile of bananas?

Comment: @jwenting And the ability to break the law of conservation.

Comment: @TylerH If you have that, all you need is a few thousand flywheels that gain speed over time without any energy input

Comment: And here we have a particle accelerator that produces a lot of antimatter. Banana for scale.

Comment: @TylerH if you can make a pile of bananas and keep them fresh breaking the law of conservation would be child't play ;)

Answer (score 23):

This is the [chart of nuclides](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html), i.e. the isotopes of all atoms.

[image: nuclides]

The green color shows that most nuclei have isotopes decaying with beta+ decay, i.e. positrons. If you go to the link there is interactive information.

From this it is seen that everyday items which will always have a tiny percentage of the long lived isotopes will be decaying into positrons, the antiparticle of an electron.

Nuclides that have too many protons will decay with beta+

> alpha, beta and gamma radiation

The "beta" in your question is both a beta+ and beta- , and yes the statement is correct.

The [beta+ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#.CE.B2.2B_decay) frees a positron into the environment of the nuclide.

$^\mathtt{A}_\mathtt{Z}X \rightarrow ^\mathtt{\hphantom{Z-}A}_\mathtt{Z-1}X' + e^+ + ν_e$

This decay is used in [positron emission tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography), because the positron meeting an electron in the environment will annihilate into two photons  and give medical information:

> Positron emission tomography (PET)[1](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html) is a nuclear medicine, functional imaging technique that is used to observe metabolic processes in the body. The system detects pairs of gamma rays emitted indirectly by a positron-emitting radionuclide (tracer), which is introduced into the body on a biologically active molecule.